# ActionSheet displaying well below view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am *attempting* to have an actionsheet that contains a pickerview display at the bottom of the screen across multiple devices (iphone4/5 namely). I would assume that to make it display flush at the bottom of the screen, you would want the Y origin of the actionsheet to be at the height of the view (push it all the way to the bottom) minus the height of the actionsheet (to move it back up on the Y axis).

This however is showing my actionsheet well below the bottom of the screen.

Code:

```
[actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 294, 320, 294)];

NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",
      self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,
      self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
```

NSLog is spitting out: `0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 372.000000

So 372-294 from the actionsheet is 78, so what gives? Obviously my logic is flawed.

Comment: Using `UIActionsheet`?

Answer (score 0):

Which view are you passing in when you call

```
showInView:(UIView*)view
```

Sounds like you may be passing in the wrong view and is offsetting your position incorrectly.

To add on to this, you shouldn't have to deal with the UIActionSheet's frame. It should position itself accordingly for you.

```
[_myActionSheet showInView:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]];
```

Will make it show up at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I don't know if this would change things, but in your example actionsheet seems to be a property, I am creating mine all in code. Using the bottom example says unrecognized selector. Hmmm

Comment: This is all done in code as well. Just change _myActionSheet to actionSheet (the name of your action sheet from your example).